# How to collect jquery.ajax() data in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I send data from javascript to PHP like this:

```
$.ajax({'url': 'my.php',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify(update_data),
        'success': function(response) {
                       alert(response);
                   }
       });
```

Using HTTPFOX Firefox plug-in I see the following data in the `POST DATA` tab:

`{"file_id":["1","2","3"],"description":["lala","kuku","wow!"],"tags":[["julia","paper"],["Very nice car"],[]]}`

however, if I do in my.php `print_r($_POST)` I see an empty array. Why is that ? How could I collect the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data needs to be in the form name=value.

try...

```
$.ajax({'url': 'my.php',
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': 'mydata=' + JSON.stringify(update_data),
        'success': function(response) {
                       alert(response);
                   }
       });
```

Then you should have your json string in `$_POST['mydata']`

You'll then need to use `json_decode` to actually get at the individual values in your string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Wouldn't it be data: { mydata: JSON.stringify(update_data) } ?

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is in JSON format. Use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to convert it to array.

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['description'], true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect your data to be in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA. Then json_decode to make sense of it.